Error in Expo Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered
i just  initialized a new expo app  and run it on android emulator  it shows  two error
Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'NativeUnimoduleProxy': java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: registerScreenCaptureObserver from pid=10391, uid=10192 requires android.permission.DETECT_SCREEN_CAPTURE, js engine:
hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

i opened the app on my physical android  mobile using expo app and scan the qr code it worked  but why its not working on the emulator
Device software is version 11
emulator software is version 14
the thing  i have an old project the (first project) i created is working on both , whenever i create a new project it shows that   error on emulator only

Which android version does your emulator use , greater than 14 ?
Which android version does your device use  older than 14 ?

my device software version  is 11  , my emulator software version is  14 , but the thin  is  i have another old  project that is working on both  , but whenever i create a new project its only work on android device and  show the error above in the emulator

after 22 hours  of testing
i fixed this by downgrading the expo version from 50  to 49
